# Python subprocess.Popen Unexpected results running ssh

Tags: python, linux, variables, ssh

This is running Python 2.7.5, on a CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) system.  I do not have a lot of experience with Python.  But I have looked at a number of previous questions/examples and cannot figure out how to proceed with this issue.  I'm unsuccessful running a Linux ssh command from a Python script.  However, when I run a Linux echo command I get expected results.  I'll provide the code and both outputs:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

tunnelUser='testuser'

localIP = []
localPort = []
remoteIP = []
remotePort = []
x = 0

vfile=open('/home/'+tunnelUser+'/development/scripts/port-dummy-data','rt')
for line in vfile:
    columns = line.split(',')
    localIP.append(columns[0])
    localPort.append(columns[1])
    remoteIP.append(columns[2])
    remotePort.append(columns[3])
    sshCommand = " -f -N "+tunnelUser+"@"+localIP[x]+" -R "+localPort[x]\
        +":"+remoteIP[x]+":"+remotePort[x]
    subprocess.Popen(['/bin/ssh', sshCommand])
    # subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', sshCommand])
    x=x+1
sys.stdout.close()
```

Yields the following negative results:

```
prompt > ./create-tunnels.py 
prompt > ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost -r 8080:192.168.1.3:8080
: Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost -r 8090:192.168.1.11:8090
: Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost -r 8081:192.168.1.5:8081
: Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost -r 8085:192.168.1.9:8085
: Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost -r 8095:192.168.1.12:8095
: Name or service not known
```

Yet when I "comment out" the ssh and "uncomment" the echo, I get the expected results:

```
prompt > ./create-tunnels.py 
 -f -N testuser@localhost -R 8080:192.168.1.3:8080

 -f -N testuser@localhost -R 8081:192.168.1.5:8081

 -f -N testuser@localhost -R 8085:192.168.1.9:8085

 -f -N testuser@localhost -R 8090:192.168.1.11:8090

 -f -N testuser@localhost -R 8095:192.168.1.12:8095
```

I believe I'm missing something simple due to lack of Python experience.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The individual arguments to `Popen()` should be passed as a list, i.e. something like

```
Popen(['/bin/ssh', '-f', '-N', tunnelUser+"@"+localIP[x], '-R', ...])
```

But instead you're passing the arguments as one giant string.  So it's trying to interpret the entire literal string `localhost -r 8080:192.168.1.3:8080` as one hostname.

Also, why does the unsuccessful output block contain the `-r` flag, when the code has it as `-R`?

Comment: ssh is interpreting everything before the "@" as the username and everything after it as the host. So it thinks the username is " -f -N testuser" and the host is "localhost -R 8080:192.168.1.3:...".

Comment: @Kenster Ah hah!

Comment: @Kenster The problem is not ssh related as the following command works fine from the command line and from a BASH script
```ssh -f -N testuser@localhost -R 8080:192.168.1.3:8080```  This is a port-forwarding (tunneling) method

Comment: @JohnGordon You answer got me closer.  I put in this line of code:

Comment: ```subprocess.Popen(['/bin/ssh', '-f', '-N', tunnelUser+"@"+localIP[x], '-R', localPort[x]+":"+remoteIP[x]+":"+remotePort[x]]) ```

Comment: Getting this bad output now: ```PROMPT > ./create-tunnels.py 
Bad remote forwarding specification '8090:192.168.1.3:8090
'
Bad remote forwarding specification '8080:192.168.1.4:8080
'
Bad remote forwarding specification '8081:192.168.1.5:8081
'
PROMPT > Bad remote forwarding specification '8085:192.168.1.6:8085
'
```

Comment: It looks like `remotePort[x]` has a trailing space; perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: No trailing space in my code, I must have copied too much when I copied that into my buffer to paste it here.

Comment: `Bad remote forwarding specification '8090:192.168.1.3:8090 '` looks like a trailing space...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221970/discussion-between-steve-hunnell-and-john-gordon).

Comment: So although there wasn't a trailing space in the code, the data had a trailing return (newline) and the ```remotePort[x].strip()``` corrected that issue.  Problem solved.